# Defining multiple typealiasses

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

While experimenting with generics in Swift I came across this problem and am not able to find an answer.

Say I have the following code:

```swift
protocol Component {
}

protocol Contains {
    associatedtype CompType: Component
    var components: [CompType] { get set }
}
```

Here, types that implement `Contains` should be able to store any type that implements the `Component` protocol specified by their typealias. If I extend the code to the following, it works as expected.

```swift
protocol Component {
}

struct SomeComponent: Component {
    init() {
    }
}

struct AnotherComponent: Component {
    init() {
    }
}

protocol Contains {
    associatedtype CompType: Component
    var components: [CompType] { get set }
}

struct Container: Contains {
    typealias CompType = SomeComponent
    var components: [SomeComponent]
}

var x = Container(components: [SomeComponent()])  // works perfectly!
var y = Container(components: [AnotherComponent()])  // fails as expected
```

Finally the question: is it possible to make `Container.components` accept both `SomeComponent` and `AnotherComponent`, but reject other types that implement the `Component` protocol? In other words, can `typealias` hold more that one type?

Thanks!

Comment: Make another protocol, that only `SomeComponent` and `AnotherComponent` inherit from

Comment: Short answer, no. The type alias serves to _resolve_ the generic associated type. It must resolve it to one type unambiguously; that is what resolution is. The way you’ve set things up, that type can and must be any Component adopter. If that’s not what you wanted, you shouldn’t have set things up that way.

Comment: @matt perfectly clear answer I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Well, I'll try giving it as an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type alias serves to resolve the generic associated type. It must resolve it to one type unambiguously; that is what resolution is.

Well, the way you’ve set things up, that type can and must be any Component adopter. That is what this line means:

```
associatedtype CompType: Component
```

You used a generic constraint of Component. If that’s not what you wanted, you shouldn’t have set things up that way. As others have suggested, if you want just SomeComponent and AnotherComponent to satisfy the generic constraint, then you would need to use a protocol that only SomeComponent and AnotherComponent adopt.

Comment: this will still fail when on the struct he defines the `typealias` on the conformer

Comment: @dmlebron But that's the whole point of my answer. Contains is a generic protocol. One Contains adopter, his Container, can only resolve the generic one way. "One type, unambiguously" is what I said. He seems to have some misconception about what the typealias does, and I am trying to correct it.

Answer (score 2):

You can conform to multiple protocols

```
typealias CompType = SomeComponent & AnotherComponent
```

Or you can do changing logic

```
protocol Component {
}

struct SomeComponent: Component {
    init() {
    }
}

struct AnotherComponent: Component {
    init() {
    }
}

protocol Contains {
    var components: [Component] { get set }
}

struct Container: Contains {
    var components: [Component]
}

var x = Container(components: [SomeComponent()])
var y = Container(components: [AnotherComponent()])
```

Comment: Does this work for you? I get `Non-protocol, non-class type 'AnotherComponent' cannot be used within a protocol-constrained type`. In my example `SomeComponent` and `AnotherComponent` were structs, not protocols. When changing it to protocols however the compiler said that `Container` no longer conforms to the `Contains` protocol.

Comment: I am checking, one moment

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the `associatedtype` at all

```swift
protocol Component {
}

struct SomeComponent: Component {
    init() {
    }
}

struct AnotherComponent: Component {
    init() {
    }
}

protocol Contains {
    var components: [Component] { get set }
}

struct Container: Contains {
    var components: [Component]
}

var x = Container(components: [SomeComponent()])
var y = Container(components: [AnotherComponent()])
```

Use `associatedtype` on protocols when you need to specify a type.

On this case you don't want to specify because you want to be able to accept a conformer to a protocol

Comment: This is true, except for the fact that I don’t want to accept all types that Implement Component, only SomeComponent and AnotherComponent.

Comment: then `SomeComponent` and `AnotherComponent` should be protocols that conform to `Component`